# How to fix stretching issue with Image Mapping?

Tags: image, vector-mapping, texture-coordinates

I'm having trouble of trying to fix this as I'm still new to Image Mapping, does anyone know why stretching happen? I'd be very grateful for someone to help as I've been stuck for several hours on trying different ways to solve this.

This is what I was expecting it to be but when it comes to the bottom part or upper part, the texture starts to stretch
[image: ..]

Here's the screenshot of my issue as I've pointed an arrow for clarity, the nodes I've used can also be seen here.
[image: ..]

[image: ..]

Comment: Try the UV output of the texture coordinate node, after unwrapping (either smart or normal) instead of the object one

Comment: @Leo, well the problem is that I don't use UV for it because of its texture, [vector image](https://i.imgur.com/ktLujxH.png) I feel it's more simple to use Object for Texture Coordinate using this vector image.

Comment: Although if there really is no other way to fix it then I'll take @Leo's suggestion.

Comment: Yes I think that if you want accuracy with texture you need to use UVs

Comment: You can have multiple Texture Coordinate Input nodes and mix and match UV,Object etc. later in the Node flow.

Comment: Alright, I'll try them, thanks for the help everyone!